# Override Twitter's Bootstrap <hr> styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the color and size of a horizontal rule, but there is bootstrap default styling. How can I override it without manually changing bootstrap css?

```
 hr {
  background-size: 4px;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFF0F2;
  border-color: #FFF0F2;
  border: 4px;

}
```

Comment: Put the styling you want in your own CSS file (eg: styles.css) and make sure you include the custom CSS flle **after** the bootstrap library.

Comment: That worked! Should I delete the question? It seems poorly phrased and too specific?

Comment: No need to delete the question. It might be helpful for another person (Probably for the beginners).

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways to add your styling to the `<hr>` element. Check the following. You can override the bootstrap styling from your styling as below.

PS: This answer is a general answer with all possibilities

**Inline Styling**

```html
<!--bootstrap cdn-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Inline styling-->
<hr style="background-size: 4px; border-top: 4px solid #FFF0F2;
  border-color: #FFF0F2;">
```

**Internal Stylesheet**

```html
<head>
<!--bootstrap cdn-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--Internal Style sheet-->
<style>
hr {
  background-size: 4px;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFF0F2;
  border-color: #FFF0F2;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<hr>

</body>
```

**External Stylesheet**

```css
hr {
  background-size: 4px;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFF0F2;
  border-color: #FFF0F2;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!--bootstrap cdn-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<hr>
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved simply by putting my custom CSS sheet *after* the Bootstrap library

Answer (score 0):

Works in bootstrap 4+ if you just want to change the color to use success/danger/etc... use bg-<theme>

```
<hr class="bg-success">
```